# How to locate ALL html tags in Selenium with Python

Tags: selenium

My code:

```
import stuff...
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\...\\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://webpage.com/')
elems = driver.find_elements_by_CLASS_ID_TEXT_XPATH_WHATEVER_ELSE_BADLY_DOCUMENTED_STUFF
```

How do I get a list of ALL CSS Selectors, such as Class, ID, p, span, input, button and all other elements from the webpage.com?

If you know a link to a brief and clear info resource with plentiful of examples explaining find_elements_by or Locating Elements in advanced detail, please share here.

edit:
ok, a bit more specific question then, how could I get the list of ALL Class Selectors from a webpage into elems?

elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('????')

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by exporting all elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath to search the DOM, there's a good tutorial on using XPath [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_nodes.asp). You may also find [this](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) resource useful which covers using XPath queries with Selenium.

You can use XPath queries with selenium like so:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button')
```

This code would return all buttons on the page.

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '[class]')
```

This would return all the elements that contain a class attribute

I hope this helps.